# Eloquent where lower() LIKE with PostgrSQL Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I wanna speed up my queries in ***PostgreSQL*** in Laravel with Eloquent.

Now I have this:

```
$word = 'Bertha'
$cows->where('name', 'ilike', '%' . $word . '%');
```

Which can be faster when I do a normal `like` instead of `ilike`.

So I tried the following:

```
$cows->where('LOWER(name)', 'like', '%' . $word . '%');
```

And

```
$cows->whereRaw('LOWER(name) like %' . $word . '%');
```

And

```
$cows->whereRaw('LOWER(name) like %?%', [$word]);
```

This all fails with errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in wich way does it fails? error or just not the result you're expecting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `DB::raw()`

```
$cows->where(\DB::raw('LOWER(name)'), 'like', '%' . $word . '%');
```